# Ubuntu or Fedora drivers for Canon imageCLASS MF632CDW colour laser printer

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

At this point it seems that Canon does not release any Linux drivers for my new laser, the Canon imageCLASS MF632CDW colour laser printer.
Does anyone know of a compatible driver that might work for this printer?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and 16.04, as well as Fedora 26.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you link the page ? Is there a tar.gz ? or just a .rpm ? A rpm is an archive, like a zip, you can extract the contents and examine the install. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html ,  it is in the repos https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rpm2cpio

Comment: The printer supports AirPrint so it should work with the driverless printing in Ubuntu 17.04 and later.

Comment: as Florian says, AirPrint supports the printer; you have 17.04: has no icon appeared in your PRINTERS folder for the Canon? If there is, and you look in the Make & Model entry in PROPERTIES for the Canon, it is likely to say "driverless": which seems to be the mark that it runs under airprint

Comment: I'm not familiar with AirPrint.  I'll give that a shot as soon as possible and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 3):

There is now an "unofficial" driver available...  I've installed it on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine and it works fine.

You can get the driver from:

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/color-laser/color-imageclass-mf632cdw?subtab=downloads-drivers

Installation instructions can be found at:

http://ug.oipsrv.net/USRMA-0586-zz-DR-enUS/frame_htmls/home.html?prd=USRMA-0586-zz

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Installation on Ubuntu will not work without making some modifications to the script. I modified the script slightly to make it work on ubuntu. You can find the [gist](https://gist.github.com/smac89/4983fb3066b293a190acd989fbe521fa) here

Answer (score 2):

An addendum to my earlier answer...

The drivers that I downloaded back in May worked well for printing, but they were awfully slow to bring up the printer dialogue.  Printing from a webpage took at least 30 seconds to open up the dialogue.  However, there must have been some recent updates that I didn't notice that really improved the response time.  Hitting Ctrl-P, for example, gives you an immediate print dialogue box.  So printing on the MF632cdw is working very well now.  This is with Ubuntu 18.04, btw.  I haven't tested this on Fedora yet.

So the next problem is getting the scanner (on the MF632cdw) to talk to the PC (over the network).  So far I am unable to scan directly from the MF632cdw to the PC, using any scanning software on the PC.  I can scan to a USB stick and walk it over to the PC without any problems, so I'm not dead in the water here, just mildly inconvenienced.  Would anyone have any thoughts on the scanning portion of the Canon?

Answer (score 0):

Install cupscloudprint.  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-a-linux-machine-to-google-cloud-print/

I have the same printer, works on LM 17.x, 18.x and Ubuntu 16.04, all of which I have at my home.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/786836)

Answer (score 0):

Original documentation from developer: [CUPS CLOUD PRINT](https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/cups-cloud-print/)

**PPA include packages for Ubuntu Xenial and Yakkety although not mentionned**

[PPA REPOSITORY here](https://launchpad.net/~simon-cadman/+archive/ubuntu/niftyrepo)

Here's the command lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:simon-cadman/niftyrepo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cupscloudprint
sudo /usr/share/cloudprint-cups/setupcloudprint.py
```

While running the script you'll get those questions:

```
~$ sudo /usr/share/cloudprint-cups/setupcloudprint.py
    Deleting old configuration file: /etc/cloudprint.conf
    Name for this user account ( eg something@gmail.com )? xxxxxxxx@gmail.com

    Open this URL, grant access to CUPS Cloud Print,then provide the code displayed : 

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudprint&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

    Code from Google: XXX1Ab34/57dj-bingoFORnadlkfjd

    You currently have these accounts configured: 
    xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    Add more accounts (Y/N)? n
    Add all Google Cloud Print printers from xxxxx@gmail.com to CUPS (Y/N)? Y
    Use a prefix for names of created printers (Y/N)? GCP
    Added Canon_MF632C634C
    Added Save_Google_Drive
    Added Brother-MFC-9340CDW
    Added MFC-9340CDW
    Added 4 new printers to CUPS
```

**Note it works also fine on GSuite account**

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and this solution works fine. Don't worry if you get error messages in terminal while installing cupscloudprint. Just follow the next steps it and run the script.

I have Canon ImageClass MF632cdw